# Jquery ajax text/html to application/json

Tags: json, jquery

I have an error on using the ajax request below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://webservice.users.com:8000/users",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic b2d1e77hbi5lcmVu1BhczRVYg");
    },
    success: function (json) { console.log(json); },
    error: function (httpReq, status, exception) {
        console.log(status + " " + exception);
    }
});
```

My call is cross-domain and it result is text/html (maybe jquery can't convert result to application/json)

Console errors:
parsererror Error: jQuery18206287364205345511_1351595013388 was not called
Error: **"SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "** in chrome browsers.

Chrome Developer Tools service response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:180
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 30 Oct 2012 10:36:57 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Set-Cookie:active_style=style; expires=Wed, 30-Oct-2013 10:36:57 GMT
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

Server response body:

```
{
    "data": {
        "islogin": "0"
    },
    "userdata": {
        "login": "0"
    },
    "rstatus": {
        "status": "0",
        "errno": "5555",
        "mesg": "blablabla"
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is in your response body?

Comment: does the API serve jsonp? If so do they require additional params in url to define jsonp output or the callback? Many API's that serve json don't serve it in jsonp format

Comment: @charlietfl web service API doesn't support jsonp format

Comment: Try to change  `dataType: 'jsonp'` to  `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: if service doesn't support jsonp, you will have to retrieve the json  with a proxy on your server or third party like YQL. Even though you are getting the response, browsers won't process it due to cross domain policies

Comment: @FAngel json not support cross-domain call (Access-Control-Allow-Origin.)

Comment: Why it does not support? Yes, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) article   (see "Simple requests" part) you can't send json to server, but I see nothing about server can't return JSON. And you already(!) receive JSON

Comment: @FAngel I receive response when using JSONP but jquery not handle response beacuse response not contains callback function. I need to manipulate response (raw response) before success, error function

Comment: I would try to change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'text'`, than in `complete` handler (as I remember it is fired before `success`) did whatever I need with it. To get a JS Object you can use JSON.parse. But still - what is wrong with using dataType:'json'? Not that you are doing something wrong, just interesting.

Comment: @FAngel I have an error when change dataType to another data type from jsonp, chrome error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://webservice.users.com:8000/users Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Hm... do you have Access-Control-Allow-Origin set on that webservice.users.com set? I do not see it in response. Well, if no one will answer this before that time I'll play with this later at home. Interesting question)

Comment: @FAngel The complete method is fired **after** success or error methods are called...